# Google Contacts, Google Drive on Google App Engine 1.7.5 JAVA

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api, guava, google-api-java-client, google-contacts-api

using

```
gdata-contacts-3.0.jar, 
google-api-services-drive-v2-rev43-1.12.0-beta.jar,
guava-13.0.1.jar
```

Google Drive works but not Google Contacts. (i tried all kinds of solutions but never got both working together on Google App Engine where as it works in local devmode.)

calling: ContactsService gservice = new ContactsService("...");

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.copyOf([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet;
>
> at
>   com.google.gdata.wireformats.AltFormat$Builder.setAcceptableTypes(AltFormat.java:399)
>     at
>   com.google.gdata.wireformats.AltFormat$Builder.setAcceptableXmlTypes(AltFormat.java:387)
>     at com.google.gdata.wireformats.AltFormat.(AltFormat.java:49)
>     at com.google.gdata.client.Service.(Service.java:558)

Comment: does not help: http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/issues/detail?id=244

Comment: Are you sure, you are using guava 13.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK now it works. Nobody was able to see that i used to

> **Add Google APIs from the Eclipse Plugin.**

This does not only just add new jars that do not work in combination but also leaves all those old ones in a subfolder in my project ".google_apis...". Somehow **those made it to Google App Engine** and the odyssey started.

After removing those ...  everything works fine. So again and, as everywhere mentioned, i was using a mixed guava version bulk which human nature does not expect to being activated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in my project, but it was solved when I used gdata 1.47.1. It can be found at http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/downloads/detail?name=gdata-samples.java-1.47.1.zip

As I am using Maven, I uploaded it to my Nexus. Added dependency in pom.xml and it was started working.

One more thing to notice, I am using guava 13.0. If it helps you.

Comment: this does not help on Google App Engine

Comment: Are you sure you are using guava 13.0?

Comment: yes i am using "guava-13.0.1.jar" there is no other. I used to have "guava-jdk5-13.0" from google-drive - i removed that. I used to have "google-collect-1.0-rc1.jar" form google contacts - i removed that too. ... and i have tested so many versions of guava. ..... After all i wonder if google app engine loads a different version that i do not manage from my eclipse. WHY does it work in local dev mode?